# Logon Trigger IP Address Issue

Tags: oracle, trigger, logon

I have this logon trigger to restrict IP addresses.   It is the same trigger I have seen everywhere.  However, it is not working as expected, and I was hoping someone could give some direction.

I am able to connect to this account / server from SQL*Plus and from a PHP script on a server where the IP is not in the list of IP's.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER check_ip_addresses_trg
AFTER LOGON
ON DATABASE

BEGIN
  IF USER IN ('JSMITH') THEN
     IF SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'IP_ADDRESS') NOT IN
       ('192.168.170.34',
        '192.168.170.39',
        '192.168.170.57',
        '192.168.170.62') THEN
       RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Can not log in from this IP address (' || SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'IP_ADDRESS') || ')');
     END IF;
 END IF;
```

But, if I try from a different server:  sqlplus jsmith/password@dbserver.dbase.com, I am able to log into SQL*Plus successfully.   From this one PHP script I wrote, I also try to connect to this account, and I am able to connect successfully.

We are running SE 11g R2.   I had expected an error message.   Any thoughts?

Comment: Sure, after you log in, check what `SELECT SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'IP_ADDRESS') FROM DUAL;` returns. Maybe it is different from what you would expect.

Comment: What those articles probably aren't telling you is that JSMITH's workstation is assigned an IP address via DHCP making this trigger almost impossible to maintain.  And, if JSMITH was an application account, nobody should have those credentials, not even a plain text *conf* file.  (use an Oracle Wallet)  Which begs the question: What Business Requirement are you trying to solve?

Comment: It is also possible that if your connection goes through a load balancer, firewall, or some other proxy that the real address of the client will be replaced with the IP of the proxy for _all_ connections. The previous comments are both correct - you need to validate what client IP is actually being set in sys_context, and the business requirement you are meeting with this check. It has no purpose unless it was for an application account connecting only from app servers with fixed IP addresses, or unless you want to ensure all connections are coming through a load balancer or app firewall.

Comment: Actually, it will be an application, on another server, connecting to this account, not an actual person.  And, it is only that application, from those IP's listed, that should be allowed to connect to Oracle.   I've verified that the IP connecting is not one in the list.  So, why is it not throwing an error?

Comment: What are the privileges of user `JSMITH`?

Comment: Are you sure the IP-Addresses are static? Typically they are assigned from a DHCP server and may change at any time.

Comment: HI, yes, the IP's are static.   In fact, I changed the code to write to a file if the IP is not in the list, and is successfully wrote to the file.  So, this proves that it is recognizing that the IP is not in the list.  So, is it my misunderstanding?   I had thought the RAISE_APPLICATION would throw some ORA- message and kick the connection........maybe I'm wrong in that?